# How to select distinct instance by date across multiple occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as follows Id, TaskId, and ActivityDate.  I am trying to select all the Ids that occur for certain conditions more than 3 times (three different days).

```
 Id     TaskId      ActivityDate
 1      CAU         2/1/2020
 2      CAU         2/15/2020
 3      INM         4/1/2020
 1      CAU         3/14/2020
 1      CIC         3/14/2020
 2      LM          6/22/2020
 1      CIC         2/15/2020
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
 ;WITH ContactAttempts AS
 (
 SELECT COUNT(TA.Id) AS Count1, TA.Id, TA.TaskId FROM 
 [tbl_Task_Activity] TA
 WHERE TA.TaskId IN ('CAU', 'CIC', 'LM', 'SA') 
 AND TA.Id = @ReferenceId
 GROUP BY TA.Id, TA.TaskId
 HAVING COUNT(TA.Id) >= 3)

 SELECT * FROM ContactAttempts
```

Which gets me the row and count for instances over 3, but I can't figure out how to get it distinct by date.  So in the sample data I've provided, ID 1 is there 4 times but since I want it based on distinct days, which would only return 3.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). it is not magic nor consequence-free.

Comment: In your code you have referenceid column but not in the sample data. Please explain.

Comment: Updated per suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to count 3 different days, You can use below query -

```
;WITH ContactAttempts AS(SELECT COUNT(TA.ReferenceId) AS Count1,
                                TA.ReferenceId,
                                TA.TaskId
                           FROM [tbl_Task_Activity] TA
                          WHERE TA.TaskId IN ('CAU', 'CIC', 'LM', 'SA') 
                            AND TA.ReferenceId = @ReferenceId
                          GROUP BY TA.ReferenceId, TA.TaskId
                         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ActivityDate) >= 3)
 SELECT * FROM ContactAttempts;
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit, but I also need to strip the time off of the ActivityDate column, forgot that part.  I'm using DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ActivityDate), 0)) but that doesn't seem to work in the HAVING(COUNT) clause

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild Nothing like changing the goalposts, huh? Just change it to `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(ActivityDate AS date))...`

Comment: @Charlieface, that wasn't in my original question, and I hated having to add it after the fact.

Comment: Needed to add a DISTINCT to the select but this got me where I needed to be.  It was activity date I needed to focus on, not Id.  Thanks @Ankit

Answer (score 0):

Add `count(distinct ActivityDate)>=3` in having clause to make sure there are three different `activitydate` within the reults.

```
;WITH ContactAttempts AS
(
   SELECT COUNT(TA.ReferenceId) AS Count1, TA.ReferenceId, TA.TaskId FROM 
   [tbl_Task_Activity] TA
   WHERE TA.TaskId IN ('CAU', 'CIC', 'LM', 'SA') AND TA.ReferenceId = @ReferenceId
   GROUP BY TA.ReferenceId, TA.TaskId
   HAVING COUNT(TA.ReferenceId) >= 3 and count(distinct ActivityDate)>=3     
)    
SELECT * FROM ContactAttempts
```